# Gnuplot:how to set the range of a specfic color in a color box

Tags: gnuplot, colorbox, legend

I want to define the range of a specific color in a palette:

For example:

```
set pm3d;
set pm3d map;
splot x*y;
```

gives:

[image]

I want red color to start from -50 to 50. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of the standard gnuplot palette, you can achieve this as follows:

The functions which define the red, green and blue values for gnuplot's standard palette are

```
red(x) = sqrt(x)
green(x) = x**3
blue(x) = sin(2*pi*x)
```

See `show palette` to see which functions are used (`rgb color mapping by rgbformulae are 7,5,15`). With `show palette rgbformulae` you find which functions are associated with this numbers.

So your example is equivalent to

```
red(x) = sqrt(x)
green(x) = x**3
blue(x) = sin(2*pi*x)

set palette functions red(gray), green(gray), blue(gray)
set pm3d map
splot x*y
```

Now, you can apply a mapping function to the `gray` value. This function must map the original gray range `[0:1]` to the new one also in the range `[0:1]`, e.g. with

```
map(x) = (x < 0.25 ? 2*x : (x > 0.75 ? 2*x - 1 : 0.5))
red(x) = sqrt(x)
green(x) = x**3
blue(x) = sin(2*pi*x)

set palette functions red(map(gray)), green(map(gray)), blue(map(gray))
set pm3d map
splot x*y
```

A good way to test palette definitions is to use `test palette`:

```
map(x) = (x < 0.25 ? 2*x : (x > 0.75 ? 2*x - 1 : 0.5))
red(x) = sqrt(x)
green(x) = x**3
blue(x) = sin(2*pi*x)
set palette functions red(map(gray)), green(map(gray)), blue(map(gray))
test palette
```

[image]